Error Registering Service Worker in Tauri Desktop App with React / Vite
I'm trying to integrate a service worker into a React application that runs in desktop mode using Tauri. However, I'm encountering an error during the registration of the service worker. The application is supposed to cache API responses, but it fails to register the service worker script in the Tauri environment, though it works fine in a standard browser environment.
Error message:

Service Worker registration failed: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://tauri.localhost/') with script ('https://tauri.localhost/service-worker.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.

main.tsx:
import './register-service-worker';
// other imports and code...

register-service-worker.ts:
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(`${window.location.origin}/service-worker.js`, { scope: '/' })
      .then(registration => {
        console.log('Service worker registered ✅', registration.scope);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
      });
  });
}

service-worker.js:
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  console.log('Service worker installed ✅');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  self.clients.claim();
  console.log('Service worker activated ✅');
});

self.addEventListener('message', () => {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  console.log(' Service worker match :)', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request).then(res => {
      const clonedResponse = res.clone();
      caches.open('api-cache').then(cache => {
        cache.put(e.request, clonedResponse);
      });
      return res;
    }).catch(error => {
      if (e.request.status !== 403) {
        return caches.match(e.request);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }),
  );
});

vite.config.ts:
import viteStaticCopy from 'vite-plugin-static-copy';

export default {
  plugins: [
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: './src/service-worker.js',
          dest: './',
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
}

I suspect the issue might be related to how paths or scopes are handled in the Tauri environment or perhaps an issue with the service worker script's availability post-build. Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide insights on what might be going wrong?
